# ForEach in SwiftUI: Error "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I'm still trying to create a calendar app and ran into another problem I wasn't able to find a solution for online.

Xcode throws the error "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" in line 2 of my code sample. I used similar code at other places before, but I can't find the difference in this one.

Also this code worked before and started throwing this error after I moved some code to the new View DayViewEvent after getting the error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions", which I hoped to fix it and would be clean code anyway.

For reference: events is an optional array of EKEvents (hence the first if) and selectedDate is (obviously) a Date.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
if let events = events {
    ForEach(events, id: \.self) { event in
        if !event.isAllDay {
            DayViewEvent(selectedDate: selectedDate, event: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you see the error? Also please reveal the structure of `event` and `DayViewEvent` if the error is related to these somehow.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini the error is in this code in line 2 under the opening curly bracket. event is just an EKEvent (events is [EKEvent]?). I wouldn't know how DayViewEvent should be the issue, since in there is just some visual stuff (Stacks, Spacers,...) and a Text grabbing the events title. What I want to add is that, after restarting Xcode, there are even more errors. "Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'EmptyView' conform to 'TableRowContent'" and other stuff. Feeling like something's fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini phew, got it running after finding some GitHub example project. Inserted "?? []" after "events", that (and some other optimizations) seems to be it... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The `body` func is called on every state change so needs to be as fast as possible thus the data needed should already be processed. So need to filter your events in a func or block, e.g. in `onAppear`:

```
struct EventsView: View {

    @State var events = [Events]()

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(events, id: \.eventIdentifier) { event in
            DayViewEvent(event: event)
        }
        .onAppear {
            events = EventsDB.shared.events(isAllDay: false)
        }
    }
}
```

And by the way, since you are using `id: \.self` because event is a reference type you need to ensure when retrieving the events that the same event always returns the same instance and not a new instance. If unique instances are returned then you need to instead use an id that is a unique property, e.g. `id: \.eventIdentifier`.

Also you should know that the SwiftUI declarative syntax inside body is not like normal programming, the ifs and for loops all generate some very complex code, e.g. `_ConditionalContent` when an if is used, read up on it here: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2021/12/09/structural-identity-in-swiftui/ or watch Apple's WWDC video [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).